# SED regular expression for file naming?

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I am new to sed regular expressions. Could someone please help me to understand what does this expression mean?

```
sed -n 's/^.*-\([0-9]*\)-.*/\1/p'
```

What I am also looking to do is basically replace singe digit numbers to double digit numbers like 1 with 01 and so would need to modify the above expression to fit that.

I have seen expressions that have the format of `\10\2\3/` in order to perform the above operation. How does this work?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

What your command is going to do is scan for a sequence of numbers between hyphens and print the numbers out.

So if your input looks, for example, like this:

```
bc-01-ddd
abc-12-ddd
abc-3-ddd
abs-5-ddd
```

Then your output will be:

```
01
12
3
5
```

To break down your command:

```
sed -n 's/^.*-\([0-9]*\)-.*/\1/p'
```

`-n` means quiet - basically "only print what I say"

And that goes with the final `p` at the and which means "print that bit" (i.e. print the output of the regular expression just before).

The quoted regular expression starts with `s/` which is a substitute, it says "find anything that matches the expression in the first pair of slashes (that is `^.*-\([0-9]*\)-.*`) and replace it with what's between the second pair ( `\1` ).

The matching regular expression says: `^.*-\([0-9]*\)-.*`

- The `^` means "from the start of the string"
- the `.*` means zero or more (`*`) of any character (`.`)
- the `-` is interpreted as a literal hyphen
- the matched `\(` and `\)` define a sub-expression, that can be used later (e.g. in the replacement part). And that's used below in this expression.
- the `[0-9]*` means zero or more (`*`) of any character between 0 and 9 -- that is the `[0-9]` means any single character between 0 and 9, and the `*` means as many of those as you find.
- the next `-` is again literal
- then you have `.*` that means any number of any character.

The replacement bit, `\1` means "the first subexpression" or the content of the match of the part of the expression between the matched brackets.  In this case it will be the sequence of digits.

To get where you want to go, you could steal something from this answer:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9137/zero-fill-numbers-to-2-digits-with-sed

and try

```
sed 's/-\([0-9]\)-/-0\1-/'
```

Which only alters where there is a *single* digit, and prepends a `0` to it, so you have two digits (and ignores the lines that already have two digits).  Note this drops the `-n` (quiet) and `p` (print) so all lines are printed.  This also relies on the hyphens in your original statement being useful.

If there aren't hyphens in your data you could try this:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]\([0-9]\)[^0-9]/-0\1-/'
```

Here the range starts with `^`, but inside a range, it doesn't mean "from the start" it means "not including" so `[^0-9]` means "any character other than a digit"

Both of these give this output with the above example input:

```
bc-01-ddd
abc-12-ddd
abc-03-ddd
abs-05-ddd
```

This page is a really good summary of sed and how to use it: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: This is soooo helpful! Thanks a ton!

Comment: This also seems to resolve my issue. sed -n 's/^.*-\([0-9]*\)-.*/\1/p' | sed -E 's/^[0-9]{1}$/0&/'